# Cassandra upgrade from 2.0 to 2.1 with hsha setting giving outofmemory error

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

1. I upgraded cassandra nodes from 2.1.0 to 2.1.1
2. I have hsha configuration in my cassandra.yaml file
3. after upgrade if I restart the service,

ERROR  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

If i change it to sync (in cassandra.yaml), cassandra nodes comes up.

Answer (score 2):

The default unlimited rpc_max_threads is causing this. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8116 for details - with HSHA enabled, it is essential to set rpc_max_threads to something reasonable for your use case.

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/conf/cassandra.yaml#L430-L434